# email: appointment confirmation

Tags: letter

I had a call with a doctor's practice, but we had a bad phone connection. I want to write them an email and confirm the date and time my appointment

*Hallo!
Wir haben uns heute telefoniert. Die Verbindung war sehr schlecht. Ich konnte Sie kaum verstehen. Ich schreibe Ihnen um meinen Termin bestätigen, für den  Fall, dass ich Sie falsch verstanden habe.*

*Mein Termin ist 2 Mai um 12 Uhr, richtig?*

Comment: This site is not meant to do translations or proof-reading, so it looks like your question is off-topic. It might be more useful in general to just include an explanation that you're not a native speaker and so your German might be a bit odd. Having a sentence like this memorized will help you in future correspondence as well. In any case, I'm sure that most doctors have dealt with people whose German is worse than yours. Another thing you can do is include the same message in English since many people in German speaking areas learn English in school.

Answer (score 2):

'telefonieren' is not reflexive.
'(sich) sprechen' can be used reflexively.

> Hallo! Wir haben <s>uns</s> heute telefoniert. Die Verbindung war sehr schlecht<s>. I</s>und ich konnte Sie kaum verstehen. Ich schreibe Ihnen, um meinen Termin zu bestätigen, für den Fall, dass ich Sie falsch verstanden habe.
>
> Mein Termin ist 2 Mai um 12 Uhr, richtig?

For style I'd change it slightly - but YMMV:

> Guten Tag,
> vorhin hatten wir telefoniert. Leider war die Verbindung sehr schlecht, sodass ich mir nicht sicher bin, Sie korrekt verstanden zu haben. Können Sie bestätigen, dass wir einen Termin für den 2. Mai, 12 Uhr vereinbart haben?

Comment: I've noticed lately you've been giving answers in German to questions posed in English. Did the policy on this change recently? Because I usually get dinged if I do the same thing the other way around. Anyway, *Hallo* and *richtig?* do sound a bit informal for the the situation, even to my ears.

Comment: No, it surely did not change... I'm just slow in changing language context and get it wrong frequently without noticing. My bad.

Comment: "12h" commonly means "zwölf Stunden" - not "12 Uhr".

Comment: Stimmt laut Duden. Danke